# What is Mailkit unique email conversation id?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit in my ASP.NET Core MVC project; is there any unique conversation id that I can use to maintain every email received?

I expect the unique conversation id will change every time a new email initiated (include if the email is forwarded) and the unique conversation id will remain the same when they reply email.

I need your advice  - thanks a lot in advance

Don

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a unique "conversation id" for email. You can, however,  group messages that are replies to each other.

If the IMAP server supports the `THREAD` extension, then you can use the [ImapFolder.Thread()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapFolder_Thread.htm) methods to return a tree structure of UIDs where they are grouped such that each child node is a reply to the parent node.

```
var threads = folder.Thread (ThreadingAlgorithm.References, SearchQuery.All);
```

If the IMAP server does not support this extension, it can be done client-side using the [MessageThreader](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_MessageThreader.htm) class.

```
var messages = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.References);
var threads = messages.Thread (ThreadingAlgorithm.References);
```

Comment: thanks, but var messages = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.References) took very long

Comment: This is why you will want to cache that info locally